# Datatable throws warning Requested unknown parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am facing a weird issue. My datatable throws following warning alert :

> Requested unknown parameter 'QualifyTime(Sec.)' for row 0 column 1

Why it doesn't find this although my array `grid` contains this parameter. Is it because the parameter Name `QualifyTime(Sec.)` contains special characters?

**Sample Array:**

```
grid = [{
  ProviderName: "ATT",
  QualifyTime(Sec.): "6.48",
  TotalServiceableOffers: "0"
}, {
  ProviderName: "CENTURYLINK",
  QualifyTime(Sec.): "3.67",
  TotalServiceableOffers: "not serviceable"
}];
```

jQuery datatable code:

```
$(tableId).dataTable({
  "autoWidth": false,
  "searching": false,
  "pageLength": 20,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "bInfo": true,
  "paging": false,
  data: gridData,
  columns: [{
    "data": "ProviderName"
  }, {
    "data": "QualifyTime(Sec.)"
  }, {
    "data": "TotalServiceableOffers"
  }]

});
```

Comment: try removing parenthesis from the column name.  . .

Comment: Does using `"data": 1` work?